# No se muestran los acentos

Tags: php, mariadb, codificación

Estoy cargando esta información desde una DB, pero cuando se muestra en el HTML no reconoce los acentos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando PDO para conectarme a la DB y uso UTF-8 en el html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisando phpMyAdmin veo que la codificación es la siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podrían asesorarme en como solventar este problema?. Gracias.

Comment: prueba con `utf8_decode($asignatura['materia'])`

Comment: @shadow, me funcionó al 100% ahora los datos se muestran con acentos y no tengo problemas. ¿Porque tenía ese error? Tengo una práctica donde todo esta por default y no tengo ningún problema, será por la codificación de la DB?

Comment: Claro @shadow muchas gracias.

Comment: hecho @MarcosRugerio

Comment: hola @VictorPerdomo no me funcionó, lo que hace tu sugerencia es quitar el fondo negro del signo ?. La sugerencia de Shadow me funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: @A.Cedano esta muy bien explicada tu respuesta en el link que me enviaste, muchas gracias por el aporte, lo voy a tomar en cuenta; de acuerdo con lo explicado mi problema estaba en el nivel 1 y con la sugerencia de Shadow se resolvió.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de la declaración de tu conexión, agrega un parámetro mas para indicar que usarás `UTF8` de modo que al declararlo quedará como atributo global para el resto de operaciones donde ocupes dicha variable de acceso a la base de datos

Tu código debería quedar así

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=agenda;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
```

Justo después de: `dbname=agenda` le indicas que usarás utf8

Así para que cuando ejecutes cualquier sentencia SQL que ocupe a `$conexion` se aplicará `UTF8` al dataset de resultados